# Change scaling algorithm for non-retina apps running in low resolution on a retina display?

Tags: display, resolution

Regarding non-retina apps running in low-resolution mode on a retina display:

- In the past, circa 2012 ([ref](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/change-osx-scaling-mode-for-retina-screen-with-non-retina-content.1428540/post-15529168)), these apps were scaled with nearest-neightbour algorithm, where 1 pixel would become a group of 4 identical pixels. Confirmed in [Apple Docs from the period](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/HighResolutionOSX/Explained/Explained.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012302-CH4-SW10)
- At some point since then, at least by 2016 ([ref](https://www.idownloadblog.com/2016/06/24/launching-apps-in-low-resolution-mode-on-retina-display-macs/)), these apps are now scaled with a bilinear (or similar) filter meaning that a single pixel does not get scaled up cleanly and the resulting group of 4 pixels is blurred with surrounding pixels

So, my question: is there a way to change the scaling algorithm back to nearest-neighbour?

Comment: The OS has changed the scaling method used. The old method no longer exists in the code: and even if it did, there's no documented way of changing it, least of all on a per-app basis. Send feedback to Apple if you want them to change it.

Comment: @benwiggy thanks for the insight! Can you give more information? Which file/function/api is this code in? Basically a reference I can quote in my Apple feedback.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a system on which I can reproduce your issue, so this is just a guess, but check out the advice on this forum post: https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/change-osx-scaling-mode-for-retina-screen-with-non-retina-content.1428540/

Namely:

1. Try using [SwitchResX](https://www.madrau.com/index.html) to enable 1:1 mode at your display's native resolution (I believe this will make your content very small; not sure whether that's a workable solution for you)
2. Use an external, non-retina display :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! That thread is where I got some of the info in the OP. I'm the most recent poster on it. Sadly none of that works for me.